# Mackey criterion for normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am wondering how Mackey's criterion works for arbitrary fields.

If there is a representation $\vartheta$ of a subgroup of $G$, then the induced representation $\operatorname{Ind}(\vartheta)$ is irreducible if and only if $\vartheta$ and $\vartheta^s$ are disjoint for all $s\in G-H$.

Does the following just work for representations over $\mathbb{C}$, or over arbitrary fields?

Let $H$ be a **normal** subgroup and $\operatorname{Ind}(\vartheta)$ reducible.

1. Does $\operatorname{Ind}(\vartheta)$ decomposes into exactly **2** irreducible representations of $G$?
2. Could the irreducible factors be isomorphic?

---

[edit]: $H$ is a normal subgroup with index $2$ in $G$ and I start the induction with an irreducible representation $\vartheta$ of $H$.

---

[edit2]: I found a similar question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127338/representations-over-mathbbq-p): The number of irreducible representations in $\operatorname{Ind}_H^G(\vartheta)$ is the index of $H$ in the centralizer $C(\vartheta)$. So the answer to the first question would be "yes".

Unfortunately I don't understand the proof. Where is the connection between this index and $\bigoplus \limits_{g\in G/H} \operatorname{Hom}_H ( \vartheta, \vartheta^g )$ ?

Comment: I am sure you forgot some hypotheses. Do you assume $\vartheta$ to be irreducible? Do you assume $H$ to have index $2$?

Comment: Thank you, I added the missing information